# strftime() fails on Raspberry Pi (Raspbian)

Tags: c++, linux, time, strftime

The program below does not work on my Raspberry Pi.  strftime() returns 0 and the variable is unset.  This exact code compiles and works great on an AS/400.  Funny, but Red Hat is having a problem as well.  The output I get on the 400 is

```
currentTime=1430852224                                
tm=SPP:0000 :1aefQP0ZSPWT  BEAK      093275 :8840:0:13
tm->year=115                                          
tm->mon=4                                             
tm->mday=5                                            
tm->tm_hour=18                                        
tm->tm_min=57                                         
tm->tm_sec=4                                          
i=20, ctimeStr=2015-05-05T18:57:04Z                   
i=13, ctimeStr=2015 18:57:04                          
timeStr=2015 18:57:04
```

On the Raspberry:

```
currentTime=1430852359
tm=0xb6dd9264
tm->year=115
tm->mon=4
tm->mday=5
tm->tm_hour=18
tm->tm_min=59
tm->tm_sec=19
i=0, ctimeStr=
i=0, ctimeStr=
timeStr=
```

I'm probably staring right at my problem, but I don't see it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

static void GetUTCTimeStr(string& timeStr)
{
    time_t currentTime;
    struct tm *tm;

    currentTime = time(0);
    cout << "currentTime=" << currentTime << endl;

    tm = gmtime(&currentTime);
    cout << "tm=" << tm << endl;
    cout << "tm->year=" << tm->tm_year << endl;
    cout << "tm->mon=" << tm->tm_mon << endl;
    cout << "tm->mday=" << tm->tm_mday << endl;
    cout << "tm->tm_hour=" << tm->tm_hour << endl;
    cout << "tm->tm_min=" << tm->tm_min << endl;
    cout << "tm->tm_sec=" << tm->tm_sec << endl;

    if (tm != 0) {
        char ctimeStr[25];
        size_t i = strftime(ctimeStr, sizeof(timeStr) - 1, "%FT%TZ", tm);
        cout << "i=" << i << ", ctimeStr=" << ctimeStr << endl;
        i = strftime(ctimeStr, sizeof(timeStr) - 1, "%Y %T", tm);
        cout << "i=" << i << ", ctimeStr=" << ctimeStr << endl;
        timeStr = ctimeStr;
    }
    else {
        cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string timeStr;
    GetUTCTimeStr(timeStr);
    cout << "timeStr=" << timeStr << endl;
}
```

I'm not sure where to look, but I should say that the **locale** command on the Pi produces this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

On the AS/400:

```
LANG=/QSYS.LIB/EN_US.LOCALE
LC_COLLATE=                
LC_CTYPE=                  
LC_MESSAGES=               
LC_MONETARY=               
LC_NUMERIC=                
LC_TIME=                   
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Print errno if i = 0.

Comment: On Red Hat, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" causes "2015-" and some graphic characters to print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The buffer is probably too small - or that is what `strftime` thinks. You wrote:

```
strftime(ctimeStr, sizeof(timeStr) - 1, "%FT%TZ", tm);
```

but you need:

```
strftime(ctimeStr, sizeof(ctimeStr) - 1, "%FT%TZ", tm);
```

It might seem to work on some platforms depending on the size of `std::string` - but only to create possible buffer overruns.

Comment: Yeah, considering `sizeof(std::string)` is pretty tiny.

Comment: @tadman Not necessarily - the small string optimization will actually lead to some "larger" `std::string` objects. Anyways, its one of the typical cases where simple typos on old-style APIs create buffer overflow problems and whatever else might go wrong.

Comment: I mean it's a random value for all intents and purpose, and appears to be 4 or 5 bytes in this case. Having variables with extremely similar names is part of the problem here. What's the best C++ alternative to `strftime` to avoid mucking about with fixed-length buffers?

Comment: Like I said, I'm probably staring right at it.  Thanks for the eyeballs, everyone.

Comment: @KellyBeard And while you fix the problem, you should make your buffer bigger than 25.  You're playing too close to the edge when you try to guess the exact buffer size needed.  I've seen too many programs crash due to trying to figure out the exact buffer size for things like this, only to have the buffer overflow by a single byte or two.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
size_t i = strftime(ctimeStr, sizeof(timeStr) - 1, "%FT%TZ", tm);
                                     ^^^^^^
```

You want `sizeof(ctimeStr)`